# Is there a reason to define a type based on xsd:token or xsd:string

Tags: xml, schema, xsd

I am working with many xsd files. I noticed that there are several type definitions based on xsd:token and xsd:string without any restriction. For example

```
<xsd:complexType name="BaseString">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:token"/>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I wonder if there is a reason for this kind of definition. Why not using xsd:token or xsd:string instead of BaseString type?
any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like very good design, but it depends on a wider context that you're not showing us with this example.

I've seen schemas that define specialized IDs.   Let's say your domain has `FooObjects`.  They're identified by `FooObjectIDs`.  Often times, `FooObjectID` will be defined as being of type `FooObjectIDType`.   That type in turn might be defined as an extension of `xsd:token` or `xsd:string`.  The type differentiates the FooObjectID as being different from (and hence handled differently than) vanilla strings.

Sometimes you see this when the IDs are "smart IDs" that are actually compound values.  Imagine customer IDs that look something like:   `CUST-VA-3391`.  A typically found bad design in all data management is these "smart keys" that encode multiple pieces of information in an ID (Virginia customer #3391).  The type for an ID like that (in my experience) is frequently something that looks like the type you have here.

The artificial type is added to create distinction between this special thing and a vanilla string, but laziness leads to lack of restriction / non-differentiation from the vanilla underlying type (xsd:token, xsd:string).

Bottom line - you create derivative types in part to imbue the type with some extra semantic; it's not a vanilla string, it's a `FooObjectID`.  But good practice would tend to suggest that further extension/restriction is appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Definitions of the form you show help document the intended use of the type, by giving it a more informative name than xsd:token.  They also help prevent inappropriate derivations and substitutions (hat-size and quiz-grade may both be small integers, but they really aren't interchangeable).

Of course, as FrobberOfBits observes, there is often an opportunity to restrict the types further using patterns or other facets. Derivations like the one shown may be missing such an opportunity; I'm less confident than FrobberOfBits that that's necessarily a sign of bad design.

Comment: Your example "hat-size and quiz-grade may both be small integers, but they really aren't interchangeable" -- is excellent.  It makes the point I was trying to make about "imbuing things with extra semantics" but in a simple example.

Comment: but when we are programming we are using an int for both of hat-size and quiz-grade and we are just using the name for distinguishing them. It is not proper to define a type for every variable. The problem appears when using an api like jaxp to create java classes for xml. If we are defining hat size based on a self-defined (baseString in my example) type then we will have a class inheriting the self-defined type. But if we are using xsd:string or xsd:int then we will have it as a field or a variable in the class.

Comment: Govan, I think what you are saying is that your XSD-to-Java-classes translator is not very smart.  That's a shame; it doesn't mean hat sizes and quiz grades should be interchangeable in XML documents.